# What is the difference between HSET and HMSET method in redis database

Tags: database, redis

In my application im using redis database.I have gone through their documentation but i couldn't find the difference between HSET and HMSET.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

HSET used to be able to set only one key-value pair. And if you needed to set several at once, you would have to use HMSET (M for multi). That was changed a few years ago, to allow both commands to accept multiple pairs. And now HMSET is redundant.

From [official documentation](https://redis.io/commands/hmset):

> As per Redis 4.0.0, HMSET is considered deprecated. Please use HSET in new code.

Comment: According to official documentation: "As per Redis 4.0.0, HMSET is considered deprecated. Please use HSET in new code."

Comment: @18augst: thanks for flagging this. Reworked my answer.

Comment: Hi, in my redis-cli which of version 4.0.9, they both work

Answer (score 20):

**[HSET key field value](http://redis.io/commands/hset):**

Sets field in the hash stored at key to value. If key does not exist, a new key holding a hash is created. If field already exists in the hash, it is overwritten.

**[HMSET key field value [field value ...]](http://redis.io/commands/hmset)**

Sets the specified fields to their respective values in the hash stored at key. This command overwrites any existing fields in the hash. If key does not exist, a new key holding a hash is created.

For more redis commands information, [click here](http://redis.io/commands).

Answer (score 6):

The only difference between the commands [`HSET`](https://redis.io/commands/hset) and [`HMSET`](https://redis.io/commands/hmset) is the **return value** of the commands.

HSET return value (Integer reply):

- `#` if the field is a new field in the hash and value was set. (where `#` is the number of new fields created )
- 0 if the field already exists in the hash and the value was updated.

HMSET returns a simple string as a reply.