# Are HSET and HMSET same in Redis

Tags: database, redis

I was going through the Redis documentation and experimenting with Redis and came across `HSET` and `HMSET` commands. And I could not find any difference between them, I tried searching, and found the following question,

[What is the difference between HSET and HMSET method in Redis database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264480/what-is-the-difference-between-hset-and-hmset-method-in-redis-database)

and accepted answer states :

> HMSET is like HSET, but it allows multiple field/value pairs to be set
> at once.

But when I tried, HSET also **allows multiple field/value pairs to be set at once.**

Please see the screenshot below, to me, it seems both work same:

[image]

Can anyone please explain to me the difference between the two. Or the use cases, where one should be used over the other.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(*I'm the author of that accepted answer in the linked topic. :)*)

Apparently, at some point since then, HSET command was updated to be variadic (same as HMSET). In my local redis version (4.0.2), it can, indeed, set multiple key-value pairs (although the command syntax hints in the `redis-cli` don't show that this is possible). However, the version which powers interactive console on redis.io still does not support that.

```
redis> HSET foo a 1 b 2 c 3
ERR ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hset' command
```

So yes, these do appear to be identical now.

Answer (score 2):

Was looking into it in 2019:)

In case someone is curious, from official documentation:

> As per Redis 4.0.0, HMSET is considered deprecated. Please use HSET in
>   new code.

https://redis.io/commands/hmset

Answer (score 1):

From **Redis 4.0.0**, `HSET` servers purpose of both `HSET` and `HMSET`.

Redis 4.0.0 [release note](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/4.0/00-RELEASENOTES) states:

> HSET is now variadic, and HMSET is considered deprecated (but will be
>   supported for years to come). Please use HSET in new code.

So, if you are using Redis 4.x+, you should use `HSET` for both single and multiple field/value pair(s).

Answer (score 0):

Anyway HMSET / HSET is an historical design and HSET does nothing more than HMSET, you can replace HSET calls with HMSET and everything works.